# cumsum as UDF in xlwings for calculating with high precision

Tags: python, decimal, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I need to apply cumsum as UDF in xlwings similar to this one below, which works fine however only for float data type.

```
import pandas as pd
@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False)
@xw.ret(index=False, header=False)    
def xl_Correl_1(x):
    return x.cumsum()
```

I need to do this cumulative sum function on numbers like this:

```
1.41421356237309504880168872421
1.41421356237309504880168872421
2.82842712474619009760337744842
4.24264068711928514640506617263
```

For highly precise calculation I am using python library "decimal". I thought of following code:

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 30

@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', pd.DataFrame.apply(Decimal), index=False, header=False)
@xw.ret(index=False, header=False)    
def xl_Correl_2(x):
    return str(x.cumsum())
```

I am aware that this is is quite unusual requirement as not everyone deals with high precision numbers and xlwings. I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Note that Excel seems to use the same 64bit floating point numbers as Python, so those decimal places past the 15 or 16th place likely aren't what you originally entered.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: @SamMason, correct. I know the limitation of excel. That's why I have to use UDF and python libraries such as decimal [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). So those numbers with 30 decimals have been indeed calculated in python with UDF in xlwings. They must be entered as a string in excel otherwise excel cannot display them.

Comment: Glad you know how to work around Excels limitations, I hoped the `str` in your function was doing that!  I don't know xlwings and don't use Excel, so probably can't help much with you actual question, sorry.

Comment: You probably have to convert the DataFrame back to strings before returning it to Excel.